# RegEx pattern any URL ending with digits.jar

Tags: regex

Please assist with the proper RegEx matching. Any URL ending with digits.jar

```
These would be valid:
http://com.abc.com/path/etc/abc/12_34.jar
http://com.abc./tpa_pemt/abc/12.22.jar

These would not:
http://com.abc.com/path/etc/abc/Source.jar
http://com.abc.com/hel_o/docs.jar
```

Comment: @anubhava, what about character before[0-9]..

Comment: @anubhava thanking for helping I got it now, its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this regex pattern

String patt="(.*\d+\.jar)$"

See the demo here https://regex101.com/r/pX6yS4/1